# Command line options to batch file (Java application)

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd

I've a java application which I run using a batch file- start.bat

Batch file:

```
@echo off

rem (

    set JAVA_HOME=.\jre7
    rem echo %JAVA_HOME%
    java.exe -jar app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

rem )
```

Manifest file has the name of class which has `public static main(String[] args)` method, and that's the start point of application.

I run the application from command prompt by typing **start.bat**

Now I need to give command line arguments to this bat file that can be received by main method.

so the task is to pass command line parameters to batch file and then send those parameter to java class main method.

I was exploring apache cli library but not sure if it can help me.

Basically this should be the input:

`start.bat -a` :
if `-a` is there then do task A in java application

`start.bat -b` :
if `-b` is there then do task B in java application

`start.bat -a -b` :
do task A and B

Help appreciated.

Thanks !

Comment: Isn't appending `%*` to the `java.exe -jar app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` enough? Arguments passed to the bat file will be accessible in main() as an elements of args[].

Comment: %* is what I wanted :) thanks !

Answer (score 1):

As user882813 points out above, the easiest solution is, if you want your `.bat` file to accept the same switches as your `.jar` file, just append `%*` (the batch variable containing all arguments) to the Java command like this:

```
java.exe jar app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar %*
```

If your `.jar` file can't accept the same switches for some reason, here's a way you can script a translation within your batch script. If you check for the existence of `-a` and `-b` within `%*`, you can construct your java launch command appropriately. This should work even if the switches are in backward order (like `start.bat -b -a`).

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "JAVA_HOME=.\jre7"
set a=& set b=& set "args=%*"

if "%*" neq "" (
    if "%args%" neq "%args:-a=%" set "a=1"
    if "%args%" neq "%args:-b=%" set "b=1"
)

if defined a (
    if defined b (
        rem :: Do both A and B
        set "cmdArgs=/ABswitch"
    ) else (
        rem :: Do work A
        set "cmdArgs=/Aswitch"
    )
) else if defined b (
    rem :: Do work B
    set "cmdArgs=/Bswitch"
) else (
    rem :: Do no work
    set cmdArgs=
)

java.exe -jar app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar %cmdArgs%
```

A quick note about the `if "%args%" neq "%args:-a=%" set "a=1"` lines: this works by variable substring substitution.  Basically, `%args:-a=%` is `%args%` with `-a` replaced with nothing.  So if `%args%` does not equal the same thing with `-a` removed, it must contain `-a`.  Therefore, set `a=1`.  See [this page](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) for more info on batch variable string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following in your batch script (after you have checked if those command line params are actually passed):

```
IF "%1" == "-a" GOTO DOWORKA
IF "%2" == "-b" GOTO DOWORKB
//as a third meassure , check for both -a and -b and invoke :DOWORKAB label

:DOWORKA
 //invoke java program with param a

:DOWORKB
//invoke java program with param b

:DOWORKAB
//invoke java program with param a and b
```

Comment: What happens if `-b` is the only argument?  It's no longer `%2`

Comment: True, hence i mentioned in paranthesis that the input should be checked for validity before the next check. I assume the programmer would take care of the initial error check and handling.